# How to remove old PDF Services in read-only file system?

Tags: macos, permission, pdf, sip

I am tidying up my print PDF services (long overdue).  But I can't find a way to delete the two "Save to..." PDF services:

[image: PDf Services]

They were created by me with Automator probably under Catalina and placed in `/Library/PDF Services`.  Since then macOS upgrades have moved them into `/System/Library/PDF Services` which is part of the read-only file system.  Their creation and modification dates are when I installed macOS 13.1, even though this is not strictly correct by 2 or 3 years!

Here they are in Terminal:

```
gilby@Beth/System/Library/PDF Services% ls -lah@e
total 80
drwxr-xr-x    5 root  wheel   160B  2 Dec 22:37 .
drwxr-xr-x  146 root  wheel   4.6K  2 Dec 22:37 ..
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root  wheel   164K  2 Dec 22:37 Save to Web Receipts
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root  wheel   164K  2 Dec 22:37 Save to iCloud Drive
lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  wheel    29B  2 Dec 22:37 Send in Mail -> /System/Applications/Mail.app
```

And when I attempt to delete and override the restricted status I get the error that they are in the Read-only file system:

```
gilby@Beth/System/Library/PDF Services% sudo rm /System/Library/PDF\ Services/Save\ to\ Web\ Receipts
override rwxr-xr-x root/wheel restricted,compressed for /System/Library/PDF Services/Save to Web Receipts? Y
rm: /System/Library/PDF Services/Save to Web Receipts: Read-only file system
g
```

I do have SIP disabled:

```
gilby@Beth/System/Library/PDF Services% csrutil status
System Integrity Protection status: disabled.
```

Question: How do I delete them?

I am running macOS 13.1 (upgraded three times from macOS 10.15 Catalina), on a 2019 iMac.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the same services installed (macOS 13.1), would assume that they are part of macOS.

```
$ ll /System/Library/PDF\ Services/
total 80
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  167504 Dec  2 12:37 Save to Web Receipts*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  167504 Dec  2 12:37 Save to iCloud Drive*
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel      29 Dec  2 12:37 Send in Mail@ -> /System/Applications/Mail.app
$ /sbin/md5 /System/Library/PDF\ Services/Save*
MD5 (/System/Library/PDF Services/Save to Web Receipts) = 22995952905c33a964e9675f4bec6a6e
MD5 (/System/Library/PDF Services/Save to iCloud Drive) = 9863dbfd1982d82b7b845300800f72ca
```

Comment: Oh!  My md5 numbers are the same as yours - that proves it. Seems like my memory is faulty about creating them - I do have a Save to Web Receipts (different location) in my ~/Library which led me astray. Thanks!